# Determine if a component is loaded Vue 3 and load a Generic component if not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am migrating a project from Vue 2 to Vue 3. I need to determine if a component is loaded and if it isn't, load a GenericComponent as a placeholder. In Vue 2 I was able to do it with the sample code. I have been reading the Vue 3 docs but I am unable to find anything about this.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import GenericComponent from 'components/GenericComponent'

if (!Vue.options.components['custom-component']) {
  Vue.component('custom-component', GenericComponent)
}
```

Comment: Why not use Vue `<component>` for dynamic components ?

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Check this out https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
const app = getCurrentInstance()
console.log('app component', app?.appContext.components['component-name'])
```

Note that `appContext.components` will only contain global components.